IF Then Else with in a Array Loop
I have an Array with some velocity data and I am trying to calculate a variable

for each speed point that is above 0 with one formula
for each speed point that is 0 with another formula.

I'm not sure why this code is not executing:
Private Sub RLF()
    Dim v1    
    v1 = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 1.7, 5.4, 9.9, 13.1, 16.9, 21.7, 26, 27.5, 28.1, 28.3, 28.8, 29.1, 30.8)

    Dim v(1 To 25) As Double

    For i = 1 To 25 Step 1
        If v(i) > 0 Then
        v(i) = v1(i - 1) * 0.277778 ' kph to m/s
        Else
        v(i) = v1(i + 1) ' keep in m/s
      
        Debug.Print v(i)
    Next i
End Sub

How can I debug the error?

You forgot an End If. As such, I'm voting to close this as "Not reproducible/typo".
